# Magento 2 Error 'WordPress doesn't appear to be installed.'

Tags: magento2.3.3

I am getting the Frontend error 'WordPress doesn't appear to be installed.'. The backend runs great. '**FishPig_WordPress**' Plugin is available on the site.

Can you please tell me how to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure that correctly. You can follow this documentation to configure this. [link](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/installation/)

I think you didn't added wordpress directory on your Magento root correctly.

If you do not have that directory then please download wordpress setup first and add that on your Magento ROOT directory or follow these steps.

[image: Magento 2 FishPig WordPress Setup guide]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: This solution is worked for me